# What is the current status of support for Asan (AddressSanitizer) and Lsan (LeakSanitizer) on Apple silicon (Arm64) MacOS?

Tags: gcc, clang, address-sanitizer, apple-silicon, leak-sanitizer

As specified in [AddressSanitizer · google/sanitizers Wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), Arm64 OS X is not officially supported yet, as verified in the discussion [gcc Apple Silicon missing AddressSanitizer/UBSanitizer libraries? · Homebrew · Discussion #3384](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3384). However, I have noticed that clang installed via Homebrew is capable of using Asan, and Lsan (kinda) works when `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1` is set. Nonetheless, there seems to be some issues with the leak check functionality, as indicated in this report: [Does LeakSanitizer not work on macOS 13 / Apple Silicon?](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/does-leaksanitizer-not-work-on-macos-13-apple-silicon/73148).

I am perplexed about the current state of support for Apple silicon (Arm64) MacOS. The Asan libraries are not built with gcc currently, and while clang supports Asan, it appears to be not fully correct and functional, contrary to the information provided in the official wiki. Can anyone shed light on the current status and provide insights into the usability and potential issues with Asan and Lsan on Apple silicon MacOS?

(All the processes proceed on Apple silicon (Arm64) MacOS)

- tried Asan (and Lsan) with gcc, turned out it's not supported yet
- then tried Asan (and Lsan) with clang, turned out the Lsan is not working correctly
- then search for status of support for Asan (AddressSanitizer) and Lsan (LeakSanitizer) on Apple silicon (Arm64) MacOS, but ended up being more confused ;(

Comment: I'm surprised there is no answer yet, its strange that still there's no tool to check for memory leaks on m1 after 4 years